# Cannot find data type date in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am getting this error message while creating table with one of the column has data type as date

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 2
>   Column, parameter, or variable #11: Cannot find data type date.

I have also tried to change the compatibility level

```
alter database test
set compatibility_level = 90
go
```

and received an error message

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2  
Incorrect syntax near '90'.
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you are trying to run?

Comment: `DATE` and `TIME` are new features in SQL Server **2008** - and to change the compatibility level, again, the `ALTER DATABASE  ... ` syntax you're using is new in SQL Server 2008 - in the 2005 version, you need to use: `EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel test, 90;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 only supports the datetime (and smalldatetime) data type.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28v=sql.90%29.aspx